# How to get origin from request headers?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

[image]

How can I get the value of this ?

Comment: try request.headers.origin

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by `req.headers['Origin']`

Please refer to: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-headers . Sails is shipped with really convenient request accessors.

Comment: I always found it most useful to `sails.log(req)` and `sails.log(res)` just to see what all is in there, as you say it's really convenient what you have access to right out of the box.

Comment: I do the same :) with Web/Node development logging is best way to check this kind of stuff

Comment: @M U: I tried req.headers['Origin'] and it returns undefined. But req.headers['origin'] works for me. Anw thanks

Comment: @Craig van Tonder: Thanks. It's really helpful

Comment: I tried req.headers['Origin'] but it did not work. Also, the documentation doens't mention any about the origin, only the host.

Comment: I would say, that at this moment you'll be better of not using Sails anymore... @MarkusAfricanus

Comment: @MarekUrbanowicz Lol yeah I'm thinking the same. I have routes in the backend that the frontend should be able to access without a user signing in but I don't want anyone to just hit the api and recieve the data